# Spring Boot Cache List

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, ehcache

I have a method which returns list. List variables are coming from database and sometimes data is updating so i want to cache list but for example in every half an hour i want to clear the cache. How can i do this with Cacheable and CacheEvict method? I tried to use them in same method as annotation but it didn't work and i have nowhere to call them other than this method.

```
@Cacheable(value = "apps")
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/30 * * * ?")
@CacheEvict(value = "apps")
public List<Apps> findLatestApps() {
List<Apps> apps = entityManager.createNamedQuery("AppsQuery", Apps.class).getResultList();
...
return Apps;

}
```

This is where i call list method;

```
public ResponseEntity<AppsResponse> getLatestApps(@PathVariable String name) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        AppsDto appsDto = appsService.findLatestApps(name);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ModelMapper().map(appsDto, AppsResponse.class), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this in the same method. Because what should the method do? Cache or Evict?

```
@Cacheable(value = "apps")
public List<Apps> findLatestApps() {
    List<Apps> apps = entityManager.createNamedQuery("AppsQuery", Apps.class).getResultList();
    ...
    return apps;
}

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/30 * * * ?")
@CacheEvict(value = "apps")
public void clearAppsCache() {
}
```

Comment: i also added to my question that where i call the list method so according to that where should i call the clear method? If i call them in the same place will it work? And in the clearAppsCache method why is it returning a list?

Comment: Sorry the return typ of clearAppsCache is a typo. You don't need to call the clear method this will be called by the scheduler

Comment: i lowered the time to 1 minute but it won't clear cache. When i tried to add new value i can not see it. Additional question does it matter where i put the clear method?

Comment: Did you add EnableCaching and EnableScheduling to your Spring Boot Application? Are the methods on a class annotated with Component?

Comment: When i add enablescheduling, program shuts down. Do i need to add anything to my pom.xml file to make it work?

Comment: no i didn't but now it works because i forgot to put @configuration annotation. One more thing right now, whenever i create new application i get 500 I/O error on POST request for nested exception. Is it because of cache?

Comment: What's in the stacktrace?

Comment: when i tried this time it didn't gave any error. I didn't understand the situation as well :) so thank you much for your effort!